# Upload and download image to php server for some processing

Tags: php, iphone, objective-c, ios, nsurlconnection

I need to upload image from iphone application to PHP server for some processing on this image on server, then after the server is finished processing , i want to return the result image to the iphone application.

i already have the code for uploading, but i can't get the result image from php server and display it within iphone application

Please help

These are the codes here:

The objective-c code for uploading:

```
NSString *urlString =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://192.168.1.3/TEST%20IPHONE/upload.php"] ;
    NSURL *nsurl =[NSURL URLWithString:urlString];  
    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:nsurl cachePolicy:NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy timeoutInterval:60.0];   
    [request setURL:nsurl];  
    [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];

    self.editingImageView.image = nil;
  NSString * filename =  @"cartoonize.png";

    NSMutableData *body = [NSMutableData data];


    NSString *boundary = [NSString stringWithString:@"---------------------------14737809831466499882746641449"];
    NSString *contentType = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"multipart/form-data; boundary=%@", boundary];
    [request addValue:contentType forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];

    // file
    NSData *imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(self.EditingImage, 90);

    [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"--%@\r\n", boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];


     [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Content-Disposition: attachment; name=\"userfile\"; filename=\"%@\"\r\n",filename]] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

    [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithString:@"Content-Type: application/octet-stream\r\n\r\n"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [body appendData:[NSData dataWithData:imageData]];
    [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithString:@"\r\n"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];



    // close form
    [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"--%@--\r\n", boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

    // set request body
    [request setHTTPBody:body];




    //return and test

    NSURLConnection * connection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] 
                                    initWithRequest:request
                                    delegate:self startImmediately:NO];

    [connection scheduleInRunLoop:[NSRunLoop mainRunLoop] 
                          forMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode];
    [connection start];
```

Here the PHP code:

```
<?php
//echo $_FILES["userfile"]["size"];
$allowedExts = array("jpg", "jpeg", "gif", "png");
$extension = end(explode(".", $_FILES["userfile"]["name"]));


if ( ($_FILES["userfile"]["size"] < 200000)
&& in_array($extension, $allowedExts))
  {
  if ($_FILES["userfile"]["error"] > 0)
    {
    //echo "Return Code: " . $_FILES["userfile"]["error"] . "<br />";
    }
  else
    {



      move_uploaded_file($_FILES["userfile"]["tmp_name"],
      "upload/" . $_FILES["userfile"]["name"]);


// some processing on the image and result image will be saved on this path upload/test.jpg

$file = "upload/test.JPG" ; 
$imageData = utf8_encode(file_get_contents($file));

echo $imageData;

}






  }
else
  {
  echo "Invalid file";
  }





?>
```

i get the data from NSUrlConnection delegate methods, so the result is in NSData object in my objective-c code, but i can't get the image from this NSData object, What do you think guys?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you implementing the `NSURLConnection` delegate methods that allow you to read the response of your request? If so, you should use an `NSMutableData` to accumulate the data being returned from your server (which is likely to be split across multiple delegate calls), then use  a `UIImage` method such as `imageWithData:` to create the image on the client. For example:

```
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response {
    self.receivedImageData = [NSMutableData dataWithCapacity:[response expectedContentLength]];
}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data {
    [self.receivedImageData appendData:data];
}

- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection {
    UIImage *finishedImage = [UIImage imageWithData:self.receivedImageData];
    self.receivedImageData = nil;
}
```

Comment: yes i did this but the image is always nil, what is the problem? is it from the server image encoding?

Comment: Why exactly are you using `utf8_encode` on the processed image data on the server? Why not just send the raw octets from `file_get_contents`? Also, it wouldn't hurt to set the header values for `Content-Type` and `Content-Length` on the response, but it should still work without them.